# compile with ssl in includes

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

```
I am trying to compile a small .c file that has the following includes:

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

gcc -Wall -o ssl-server SSL-Server.c -L/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto

Comment: Ok... now we need to know what your actual question is...

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
i 've error cimpilation
/tmp/ccEVqqFp.o: dans la fonction « main »:
client.c:(.text+0xa4): référence indéfinie vers « init_OpenSSL »
client.c:(.text+0xd7): référence indéfinie vers « handle_error »
client.c:(.text+0x11b): référence indéfinie vers « handle_error »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```